# Analyzing Energy in NS-2

Tags: ns2, energy

I am working on MANET and want to do simulation in NS-2. My certain interest is in analyzing the energy consumption in various node for transmission and setup network. I will try to improve some routing protocol for better energy conservation.

Now, my question is which parameters I have to analyze and compare? And how I can do it through analyzing Trace file information?

Second part:

> N -t 22.000932 -n 2 -e 97.796369
>
> N -t 22.001838 -n 0 -e 97.796686
>
> N -t 22.001839 -n 2 -e 97.796191
>
> r 22.001853109 *1* AGT  --- 12 tcp 60 [13a 1 0 800] [energy 97.796341
>   ei 2.199 es 0.000 et 0.000 er 0.004] ------- [0:0 1:0 32 1] [0 0] 1 0
>
> s 22.001853109 *1* AGT  --- 13 ack 40 [0 0 0 0] [energy 97.796341 ei
>   2.199 es 0.000 et 0.000 er 0.004] ------- [1:0 0:0 32 0] [0 0] 0 0 N -t 22.002472 -n 0 -e 97.796447

now my question is 
What does it means ?

> N -t 22.001839 -n 2 -e 97.796191

Answer (score 1, accepted):

N -t 22.001839 -n 2 -e 97.796191

**here N -t -> Simulation_time**

**-n 2 -> node id is 2**

**-e 97.761691 -> remaining energy level**

Comment: Thank you sir.

I have calculated total energy in transmission and per packet energy. 

Is there any other parameter that I have to calculate for analyzing a routing protocol?

Comment: @ Mazhar ,if u want to analyze your routing protocol performance you can calculate throughput, packet delivery ratio, delay, end-to-end delay and routing overhead.

Answer (score 0):

1-  Analyzing tr File trace

The new trace format as seen above can be can be divided into the following fields :

Event type

In the traces above, the first field (as in the older trace format) describes the type of event taking place at the node and can be one of the four types:

s
send
r
receive
d
drop
f
forward
General tag
The second field starting with "-t" may stand for time or global setting
-t
time
-t
* (global setting)
Node property tags
This field denotes the node properties like node-id, the level at which tracing is being done like agent, router or MAC. The tags start with a leading "-N" and are listed as below:
-Ni:
node id
-Nx:
node's x-coordinate
-Ny:
node's y-coordinate
-Nz:
node's z-coordinate
-Ne:
node energy level
-Nl:
trace level, such as AGT, RTR, MAC
-Nw:
reason for the event. The different reasons for dropping a packet are given below:
"END"
DROP_END_OF_SIMULATION
"COL"
DROP_MAC_COLLISION
"DUP"
DROP_MAC_DUPLICATE
"ERR"
DROP_MAC_PACKET_ERROR
"RET"
DROP_MAC_RETRY_COUNT_EXCEEDED
"STA"
DROP_MAC_INVALID_STATE
"BSY"
DROP_MAC_BUSY
"NRTE"
DROP_RTR_NO_ROUTE i.e no route is available.
"LOOP"
DROP_RTR_ROUTE_LOOP i.e there is a routing loop
"TTL"
DROP_RTR_TTL i.e TTL has reached zero.
"TOUT"
DROP_RTR_QTIMEOUT i.e packet has expired.
"CBK"
DROP_RTR_MAC_CALLBACK
"IFQ"
DROP_IFQ_QFULL i.e no buffer space in IFQ.
"ARP"
DROP_IFQ_ARP_FULL i.e dropped by ARP
"OUT"
DROP_OUTSIDE_SUBNET i.e dropped by base stations on receiving routing updates from nodes outside its domain.
Packet information at IP level
The tags for this field start with a leading "-I" and are listed along with their explanations as following:
-Is:
source address.source port number
-Id:
dest address.dest port number
-It:
packet type
-Il:
packet size
-If:
flow id
-Ii:
unique id
-Iv:
ttl value
Next hop info
This field provides next hop info and the tag starts with a leading "-H".
-Hs:
id for this node
-Hd:
id for next hop towards the destination.
Packet info at MAC level
This field gives MAC layer information and starts with a leading "-M" as shown below:
-Ma:
duration
-Md:
dst's ethernet address
-Ms:
src's ethernet address
-Mt:
ethernet type
Packet info at "Application level"
The packet information at application level consists of the type of application like ARP, TCP, the type of adhoc routing protocol like PUMA, DSR, AODV etc being traced. This field consists of a leading "-P" and list of tags for different application is listed as below:
-P arp
Address Resolution Protocol. Details for ARP is given by the following tags:
-Po:
ARP Request/Reply
-Pm:
src mac address
-Ps:
src address
-Pa:
dst mac address
-Pd:
dst address
-P dsr
This denotes the adhoc routing protocol called Dynamic source routing. Information on DSR is represented by the following tags:
-Pn:
how many nodes traversed
-Pq:
routing request flag
-Pi:
route request sequence number
-Pp:
routing reply flag
-Pl:
reply length
-Pe:
src of srcrouting->dst of the source routing
-Pw:
error report flag ?
-Pm:
number of errors
-Pc:
report to whom
-Pb:
link error from linka->linkb
-P cbr
Constant bit rate. Information about the CBR application is represented by the following tags:
-Pi:
sequence number
-Pf:
how many times this pkt was forwarded
-Po:
optimal number of forwards
-P tcp
Information about TCP flow is given by the following subtags:
-Ps:
seq number
-Pa:
ack number
-Pf:
how many times this pkt was forwarded
-Po:
optimal number of forwards
This field is still under development and new tags shall be added for other applications as they get included along the way.

for more information you can visit our Laboratory
www.wsnlab.org