# Analyzing Energy in NS2

Tags: ns2, energy

I need to *analyze the energy* for nodes in NS2. I was searching a lot about how to do this and I found a related question was answered  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20034182/analyzing-energy-in-ns-2), but what I need is a little bit different. I need to understand what each parameter in the tr file represents, **especially the parameters related to energy**. In addition, I am searching for a TCL script that could be used to calculate and analyze the energy.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ns2: Analyze energy : Read the latest "overview" ... and try out all 10 energy scripts https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1rU_MFAEl1GCLMTJPLR3zbxPxkQQHkQ7T?usp=sharing .... ~3000 simulations https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7S255p3kFXNSmRYb2lGcDRUdWs?usp=sharing

Comment: @KnudLarsen Thanks A lot for the attached links it's so helpful. I've noticed that all the scripts in the first links are AWK & Perl scripts, but I asked about a TCL script to analyze the energy especially the residual energy to integrate the script with the K-means TCL script that I need to analyze its energy.

Comment: ns2 : There are no tcl files for "analyzing energy". Analyzing scripts are `awk, perl, shell` scripts. .... The are plenty of ns2 simulation with "EnergyModel" https://drive.google.com/file/d/1g8WnlHHHnNXBLc0rwJY4i1z9uieKtl9s/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @KnudLarsen A lot of thanks to you.

Comment: K-MEANS-all.tar.gz https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jmbAUlbGeIF6b8vHNOkW2ub_z88Lnx1e/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @KnudLarsen Big thanks to you. The last link is so helpful❤❤.